# create nested sum json object from plain array of objects based on input fields

Tags: javascript

I am building a UI to allow user to slice and dice some FIX messages data into some d3 charts. FIX message comes with some fields and value pairs, so I have processed them into an array of objects that contain those pairs. e.g.

```
let obj = [
{'8': 'FIX.4.2', 'Account': 'Client1', 'Symbol': '1234.T', 'Side': '1', 'LastPx': 6000, 'LastQty': 100},
{'8': 'FIX.4.2', 'Account': 'Client2', 'Symbol': '1235.T', 'Side': '1', 'LastPx': 7000, 'LastQty': 200},
{'8': 'FIX.4.2', 'Account': 'Client1', 'Symbol': '1234.T', 'Side': '2', 'LastPx': 4000, 'LastQty': 50},
{'8': 'FIX.4.2', 'Account': 'Client2', 'Symbol': '1234.T', 'Side': '2', 'LastPx': 5000, 'LastQty': 200},
{'8': 'FIX.4.2', 'Account': 'Client1', 'Symbol': '1234.T', 'Side': '5', 'LastPx': 4500, 'LastQty': 100},
{'8': 'FIX.4.2', 'Account': 'Client1', 'Symbol': '1235.T', 'Side': '5', 'LastPx': 6000, 'LastQty': 100},
{'8': 'FIX.4.2', 'Account': 'Client2', 'Symbol': '1234.T', 'Side': '5', 'LastPx': 5500, 'LastQty': 150}
]
```

It becomes challenging when I wanted to have such a function that allow the following inputs, and outputs as:

```
function slicer_and_dicer(obj, arr){
......
}
```

where obj is the parsed FIX object, and the array is the fields that you want to nest the object into. The element order in the array matters. e.g.

```
slicer_and_dicer(obj, ['Account', 'Symbol'])
```

will give output of the nested json object which sums the totalnv = lastpx * lastqty below:

```
{
'Client1':{
           '1234.T':{ 'TotalNV': 1250000 },
           '1235.T':{ 'TotalNV': 600000 }
          },
'Client2':{
           '1234.T':{ 'TotalNV': 1825000 },
           '1235.T':{ 'TotalNV': 1400000 }
          }
}
```

I can build a function to create a similar object if the given element in the array is known, but if it become dynamic, e.g. adding a new level of 'Side'

```
slicer_and_dicer(obj, ['Account', 'Symbol', 'Side'])
```

Can someone share a solution? Thanks!

Comment: where's the JSON you mention in the title? Also, have you tried to solve your own problem? doesn't look like you've done any code where `......` is

Comment: the expect output json:
`{
'Client1':{
           '1234.T':{ 'TotalNV': 1250000 },
           '1235.T':{ 'TotalNV': 600000 }
          },
'Client2':{
           '1234.T':{ 'TotalNV': 1825000 },
           '1235.T':{ 'TotalNV': 1400000 }
          }
}`

Comment: use `JSON.stringify(someobj)` to get JSON from a javascript object - and what you've put in that comment is NOT JSON, since JSON only uses `"` not `'`

Comment: @slider - it's in the question ... `totalnv = lastpx * lastqty`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will do what you want

```js
let obj = [
    {'8': 'FIX.4.2', 'Account': 'Client1', 'Symbol': '1234.T', 'Side': '1', 'LastPx': 6000, 'LastQty': 100},
    {'8': 'FIX.4.2', 'Account': 'Client2', 'Symbol': '1235.T', 'Side': '1', 'LastPx': 7000, 'LastQty': 200},
    {'8': 'FIX.4.2', 'Account': 'Client1', 'Symbol': '1234.T', 'Side': '2', 'LastPx': 4000, 'LastQty': 50},
    {'8': 'FIX.4.2', 'Account': 'Client2', 'Symbol': '1234.T', 'Side': '2', 'LastPx': 5000, 'LastQty': 200},
    {'8': 'FIX.4.2', 'Account': 'Client1', 'Symbol': '1234.T', 'Side': '5', 'LastPx': 4500, 'LastQty': 100},
    {'8': 'FIX.4.2', 'Account': 'Client1', 'Symbol': '1235.T', 'Side': '5', 'LastPx': 6000, 'LastQty': 100},
    {'8': 'FIX.4.2', 'Account': 'Client2', 'Symbol': '1234.T', 'Side': '5', 'LastPx': 5500, 'LastQty': 150}
];

function slicer_and_dicer(obj, arr) {
    let ret = {};
    obj.forEach(o => {
        const e = arr.reduce((r, k) => (r[o[k]] = r[o[k]] || {}), ret);
        e.TotalNV = (e.TotalNV || 0) + o.LastPx * o.LastQty;
    });
    return ret;
}

console.log(slicer_and_dicer(obj, ['Account', 'Symbol']));
console.log(slicer_and_dicer(obj, ['Account', 'Symbol', 'Side']));
```

Comment: yes, that solves parts of the problem. since the number of levels are fixed here, what if the array is dynamic, e.g. ['Account', 'Symbol', 'Side'], or ['Account', 'Symbol', 'someotherfield']...... then it should require some iterations

Comment: I was messing with you with that code @ctlkkc seeing as you've written *nothing* - anyway, I always had the solution to "dynamic" part of your question - see edited answer